# Why doesn't t.Fail() accept string arguments?

Tags: go, go-testing

I am trying to improve my Golang tests. And I was reading this: https://ieftimov.com/post/testing-in-go-failing-tests/

I was using `t.Fatal("message")` a lot, when instead I should have been using a combination of:

```
t.Fail()
t.Logf()
```

so why on Earth is there not a single call then can fail the test and log the reason why? Is there a way for me to add such a method to a test.Testing instance?  I just want to do:

```
t.FailWithReason("the reason the test failed")
```

does this exist and if not can I add it somehow?

Comment: Why do you have a problem with `t.Fatal`? It seems to do what you want it to. https://golang.org/src/testing/testing.go?s=24932:24975#L706 There is also `t.Error` if you don't want to `FailNow`. https://golang.org/src/testing/testing.go?s=24630:24673#L694

Comment: maybe `t.Fatal()` is a misnomer, I don't want the process to exit?

Comment: Yeah, `t.Fatal` does not exit the process. Your `defer`s will even still run. It only fails the test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation and source code for the testing package.

The [documentation has an example](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/) of typical use:

```
func TestAbs(t *testing.T) {
    got := Abs(-1)
    if got != 1 {
        t.Errorf("Abs(-1) = %d; want 1", got)
    }
}
```

The documentation for `t.Errorf` is:

```
// Errorf is equivalent to Logf followed by Fail.
```

which is very similar to what you say you want:

```
t.Fail()
t.Logf()
```

Comment: if this does what I want, it's a misnomer for sure

Comment: Why do you think this is a misnomer?